# Admob capping is not respected

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm working on a project where Admob has been implemented and capping is set at no more than 1 impression per user every 5 minutes (for my tests).

But the ads are spamming.

i've followed the documentation here :

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

but the capping is not respected.

The previous developer has implemented the call in the interstitialDidReceiveAd, which is strongly NOT recommended by the doc

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
   NSLog(@"interstitialDidReceiveAd");
   if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
   }
}
```

What i've tried to do is to make the call from my viewDidAppear method but now my ads are never shown

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:YES];

   [newtopicsBtn.titleLabel setFont:PANTON_SEMIBOLD([UniversalMethod setFontsize:12])];
   [newtopicsBtn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [newtopicsBtn.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"home_newtopics_title", @"")]; 

   if(self.interstitial.isReady) {
   [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
   }
 }
```

Did you guys already face to that kind of issue ?